# Get the total value of each item in an array with Angular 2

Tags: angularjs, angular, angular2-directives, angular2-services

I have an array of shirts, each shirt has a price and I would like to get the total price of all the shirts using Angular 2.

This is what my data looks like:

```
shirts: [
{
 name: 'shirt 1',
 cost: '20'
},
{
 name: 'shirt 2',
 cost: '10'
},
{
 name: 'shirt 3',
 cost: '10'
}
]
```

I would like to then add the costs together and display in my component This is roughly where I have got to so far:

```
export class ShirtsListComponent {
  shirts: Shirts;

  constructor(@Inject(Shirts) csp: Promise<Shirts>, cdRef: ChangeDetectorRef) {
    csp.then((cs) => {
      this.shirts = cs;
      cdRef.reattach();
    });

    for (var shirt in this.shirts) {
      console.log(shirt);
    }
  }
}
```

Trouble is that `console.log(shirt)` returns nothing here and even if it did I am unsure how to then add the new `shirt` items together. Another element to this question is should I be doing this on the component or in the service?

**Edit:**
I made the following changes but I am getting `0` and I should be getting `40`

html:

```
<ul class="list-group">
  <li class="list-group-item" [shirtListItem]="shirt" *ngFor="#shirt of shirts"></li>
</ul>
<pre>{{totalShirts}}</pre>
```

Updated ShirtComponent:

```
export class ShirtListComponent {
  shirts: Shirts;
  totalShirts:number = 0;
  constructor(@Inject(Shirts) csp: Promise<Shirts>, cdRef: ChangeDetectorRef) {
    csp.then((cs) => {
      this.shirts = cs;
      cdRef.reattach();
      this.shirts.forEach(s => this.totalShirts += s.cost );
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Your for-loop is called before the promise is resolved.
You could do the for-loop inside the promise resolve function. like this:

```
export class ShirtsListComponent {
shirts: Shirts;
totalCost:number = 0;
  constructor(@Inject(Shirts) csp: Promise<Shirts>, cdRef: ChangeDetectorRef) {
    csp.then((cs) => {
      this.shirts = cs;
      cdRef.reattach();
      this.shirts.forEach(s => this.totalCost += s.cost );
    });
  }
}
```

**Update**
Your Json structure has the cost property as a string type which should be edited to be of number type like this:

```
shirts: [
{
 name: 'shirt 1',
 cost: 20
}
...
]
```

Alternatively, you can change the line where you sum the cost to be:

```
this.shirts.forEach(s => this.totalCost += parseFloat(s.cost) );
```

About the other element of your question:

From angular2 website:

> A service is typically a class with a narrow, well-defined purpose. It should do something specific and do it well.
>
> Examples include:
>   - logging service
>   - data service
>   - message bus
>   - tax calculator
>   - application configuration

In relation to your question, for me, it makes sense to put the cost calculation on the service only if the total cost is always calculated including all shirts and not just part of the list.

Examples:
**Total cost on service**: if the total cost needs to be calculated only once  probably after retrieving the shirts list on backend "it will also make more sense to move the calculation to the server backend".

**Total cost on component**: if you are only showing the total cost of the shirts currently showing on the page, the shirts currently added to the shopping cart, the shirts currently selected by user ... and so on

Comment: Awesome answer Abdulrahman thanks for including the explanation about Services and Components really helpful, I think in the end I would be best doing it via the Service but I tested what you suggested and I am getting `0` which seems wrong to me I was expecting `40` I have added my changes in the edit above.

Comment: Are you sure that csp is a promise? does it get resolved?

Comment: @Daimz sorry I overlooked the problem.  In your json, the cost type is string. it should be a number, I will update my answer with details

Comment: Still not working however it did help me with another problem I was having trying to use a pipe to convert the number to currency. I am wondering thought if perhaps it has something to do with async or how the items are loaded, because I noticed when I refresh I see `total: 0` and then the Shirts load. I tried adding `total: {{totalCost | async}}` but that just threw an error but could it be something along those lines?

Comment: @Daimz You shouldn't be using the async pipe with totalCost. The totalCost should've get updated along with the shirts load. Would you please create a plunker with your code? because I can't see any problems other than the ones I mentioned on my answer.